# Non-RESTFul Rails XML api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have a small API that I am writing in rails 3. This is not a restful application so I use a controller called api that has some methods such as:

```
def users
  @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
           format.any do
                  render :xml => @users.to_xml
            end
    end
  end
end
```

My routes (with comments etc removed) file looks like this:

```
resources :shows
resources :users

resources :comments 

devise_scope :user do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new"
end


root :to => 'home#index'

match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

When I call api/users I get the XML wrapped in HTML tags (in the body actually) but if I call api/users.xml I get a 406 error?

Do I need to change my routes to accommodate the XML call?

Thanks,

s

Comment: what does your routes file look like now? what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Cheers @DavidGrandinetti, I updated my question with the routes file.

Comment: Could you post the log message where you get the 406 error? I'd like to see the request url and the params etc. From your routes I am not clear how your api/users call is working because there does not seem at first glance a matching route in there. Only thing I can think of is that somehow the default route is matching.

Comment: Got is sorted, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new route to routes.rb and it worked:

```
match 'api/users.:format' => 'api#users', :constraints => {:format => /(xml)/}
```

j